# React useForm: после очистки поля, его нельзя заполнить данными

Tags: reactjs, form, react-hook-form

Рабочий пример в песочнице: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-thunder-8ymnpx?file=/src/App.js:840-849

0. В проекте используется комбинация библиотек react-hook-form + react-input-mask
1. В форме используются 2 типа полей: обычные input и поля InputMask
2. Заполнение и очищение полей происходит через react-hook-form (setValue, reset)

Проблема #1: Если нажать "заполнить" - все поля заполняются данными в штатном режиме. Но если нажать "очистить", а после этого "заполнить" -  обычные input заполняются данными, а InputMask остаётся пустым. Почему это происходит и как этого избежать?

Проблема #2: Если нажать "заполнить" - в InputMask приходят данные, но при клике на само это поле, оно сразу очищается. Как сделать, чтобы данные при клике не пропадали?

```
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      surname: "",
      masked: ""
    }
  });

  const data = {
    name: "Name",
    surname: "Surname",
    masked: "012-345"
  };

  function handleFill() {
    methods.setValue("name", data.name);
    methods.setValue("surname", data.surname);
    methods.setValue("masked", data.masked);
  }

  function handleClear() {
    methods.reset();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>react-hook-form + react-input-mask</h1>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input" {...methods.register("name")} />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="input"
          name="surname"
          {...methods.register("surname")}
        />
        <InputMask
          type="text"
          placeholder="InputMask"
          name="masked"
          mask="999-999"
          inputRef={methods.register("masked").ref}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={handleFill}>Заполнить</button>{" "}
        <button onClick={handleClear}>Очистить</button>
      </FormProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в передаче ссылок между компонентами. Используйте [Controller - компонент-обертку для работы с внешними управляемыми компонентами](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/) из `react-hook-form`.

`inputRef={methods.register('masked').ref}` достаточно старое решение в библиотеке, которая обновлялась 4 года назад. Поэтому сейчас удобнее использовать контроллер из `react-hook-form`. В свойстве `render` передать компонент `InputMask` с нужными настройками, и в `field` в том числе уже будет правильный `ref`. Это решит и 1ю и 2ю ваши проблемы.

```
<Controller
  name='masked'
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field }) =>
    <InputMask
      {...field}
      mask='999-999'
      type='text'
      placeholder='InputMask'
    />}
/>
```